# ReferenceError: body is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, controller, components, angular7

I'm trying to make an editpost function to my app but I keep getting an error that says "body is undefined"

> ReferenceError: body is not defined
>       at EditPost (C:\server\controllers\posts.js:161:36)

I included the controller, component and html.

for the controller

```
editPost(req, res) {
    console.log(body);
    const Schema = Joi.object().keys({
      post: Joi.string().required(),
      id: Joi.string().optional()
    });
    const { error } = Joi.validate(body, Schema);
    if (error && error.details) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        msg: error.details
      });
    }
    const body = {
      post: req.body.post,
      created: new Date()
    };

    Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, body, { new: true })
      .then(post => {
        res
          .status(httpStatus.OK)
          .json({ message: "Post updated successfully", post });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
          message: err
        });
      });
  }
```

the post component

```
SubmitEditedPost() {
    console.log(this.editForm.value);
    const body = {
      id: this.postValue._id,
      post: this.editForm.value.editedPost
    }
    this.postService.editPost(body).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.socket.emit('refresh', {})
    }, err => console.log(err))
    M.Modal.getInstance(this.modalElement).close();
    this.editForm.reset();
  }
```

And the HTML

```
        <div class="container">
      <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <h4>
              Edit Post
              <button class="button"(click)="CloseModal()"> Close </button>
          </h4>
          <p *ngIf="postValue"> {{postValue.post}} </p>
          <form [formGroup]="editForm" novalidate>
            <textarea formControlName="editedPost" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="secondary-content deleteBtn btn">Delete</button>&nbsp;
                <button class="btn" (click)="SubmitEditPost()" >Save</button>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: editPost function 1st line should be like console.log(req.body) and when you're validating use req.body not body only or you can simply add const { body } = req; as first line of editPost function

Comment: Inside editPost()  check this line `const { error } = Joi.validate(req.body, Schema);`

Answer (score 0):

> Remove `console.log(body);` in your code. Because it used before define the variable

or

define `body` variable  in before use it, So you should move the below code on top.

```
const body = {
      post: req.body.post,
      created: new Date()
    };
```

Comment: I already answered the same. Also the body is getting used in the Joi.validate(body, Schema); will throw the error too.

Comment: But I answered before your answer. And informed the details in my answer as well . :( :)

Answer (score 0):

Define the body at the top of `editPost` function

```
editPost(req, res) {
    const body = {
      post: req.body.post,
      created: new Date()
    };
    console.log(body);
    const Schema = Joi.object().keys({
      post: Joi.string().required(),
      id: Joi.string().optional()
    });
    const { error } = Joi.validate(body, Schema);
    if (error && error.details) {
      return res.status(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        msg: error.details
      });
    }


    Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, body, { new: true })
      .then(post => {
        res
          .status(httpStatus.OK)
          .json({ message: "Post updated successfully", post });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
          message: err
        });
      });
  }
```